# Unable to compile clippy (swf clipboard utility)

Tags: flash, haxe

I am having trouble compiling clippy using the instructions here: https://github.com/mojombo/clippy/blob/master/README.md

I've downloaded clippy and have tried compiling on Mac, Linux, and Windows and I keep getting the same result: The swf compiles with no apparent errors but when I try to load the clippy.swf in my webpage it is unresponsive. I've tried custom builds that others have done and it works fine - just building my own results in a dud. (and yes I do have haxe and swifmill installed). The only thing I can think of is perhaps the latest version of swifmill or haxe is causing the issue.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the commit date and the [haxe news](http://haxe.org/com/news), *Haxe 2.02* was the latest version at that time.

There is a pull request *[Updating for newer swfmill/haxe versions](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy/pull/16)* which you could try. Also take a look at some of the other [forks](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy/network), there are several claiming to work with newer haxe versions, like [this one](https://github.com/orangemug/clippy) for example.

Anyway, I don't see what this widget is doing other than creating a button which calls

```
flash.system.System.setClipboard(text);
```

It shouldn't be to hard to recreate this for the latest haxe version, if none of the forks should work.

Comment: Your answer encouraged me to just create it using Flash Pro. I found a fla that gave me a good head start here: http://www.juanchez.com/tag/clippy/